# Recursive RPATH in macOS

Tags: macos, linker, dynamic-linking, rpath

The directory structure of a framework is like this:

```
   fw.framework
      Versions
         A
            fw
            Libraries
               a.dylib
               b.dylib
         Current -> A
      Libraries -> Versions/Current/Libraries
      fw -> Versions/Current/fw
```

Dependencies:

- `fw` links to `a.dylib`
- `a.dylib` links to `b.dylib`

`a.dylib` and `b.dylib` have the *install name* `@rpath/a.dylib` and `@rpath/b.dylib`.

The *RPATH* of `fw` is set to `@loader_path/Libraries`, so that it can find `a.dylib`.

But the *RPATH* of `a.dylib` is set to `@loader_path`, because its dependency `b.dylib` is in the same directory.

Will this work? Will the linker use the *RPATH* of `a.dylib` (and not the one of `fw`, when recursively linking `b.dylib`)

And will `@loader_path` in the *RPATH* of `a.dylib` refer to the directory of `a.dylib`, and not that of `fw`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

If you use `otool -l <dylib>`, you will find (in my case):

```
Load command 22
          cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 32
         path @loader_path/../lib (offset 12)
```

`@loader_path` will be resolved to path to folder which contains `<dylib>`, so each dylib will have itself `@loader_path`.

As above, `LC_RPATH` means `@rpath_path` will have different path in different dylib, it won't be inherited from another.

So, when you load `fw`, `@loader_path` of `fw` is its **dirname**, load `a.dylib`, `@loader_path` of `a.dylib` is its **dirname**.